# Parâmetros para regras de negócio cadastrados no banco de dados

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, aplicação-web, design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

**Boa noite,**

Recentemente me deparei com uma situação que me deixou muito em dúvida, é módulo de um sistema que calcula o valor a ser pago por um serviço e para isso todas as regras estão expressas em uma tabela no banco de dados, para exemplos vamos imaginar a tabela abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos imaginar que são muitas regras que estão cadastradas e que esses são parâmetros para verificar se o valor a ser pago pelo serviço é inteiro ou apenas a metade, quero a opnião sobre como vocês implementariam tal caso.

### O que que já passou na minha mente ?

Implementar um objeto RegraDeCalculo e no método calcularPagamento do objeto Servico ele iria receber como parâmetro o RegraDeCalculo, exemplo:

```
$servico = new Servico(etc...);
$valorServico = $servico->calcularPagamento($regraDeCalculo);
//$regraDeCalculo consegue consultar o banco em busca da regra específica para o serviço
```

Realmente estou bem perdido já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressar regras de negócio em colunas de uma tabela no banco de dados não é uma boa prática. Se você precisar mudar algo na regra, irá ter que mudar a estrutura de seu banco e isso provavelmente quebrará seu código.

Acredito que você esteja indo pelo caminho certo. Eu separaria as regras por tipo em uma classe a parte, com métodos com uma única responsabilidade cada, de modo que se você precisar mudar algo, você só vai precisar alterar uma ou outra linha de código.

Comment: Muito obrigado, tirou minha dúvida.